# What are the steps to take the derivative of this function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, moment-generating-functions

This calculus derivation is giving me an extremely difficult time. I am having trouble understanding how to manipulate the $e^t$. The function is

$$P*{e}^t/[(1-q)*{e}^t]$$

I want to take the derivative with respect to $t$ so $d/dt$. The answer to this problem is 
$$[pe^t(1-qe^t)+qe^tpe^t]/(1-qe^t)$$

Any help with basic understanding of how to differentiate these functions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That was my original method of doing the problem. But I guess it is not the case, it might be because e^t is dependent on a continuous random variable since this function is a moment generating function that I am taking the derivation for.

Comment: Okay, now, which items are functions of $t$?

Comment: Either you have a typo in your function definition, either you did not notice that Exp[t] is a multiplying term in both numerator and denominator. If this is the case, start simplifying your expression. Please edit your question (are you sure that the denominator is (1-q)Exp[t] and not 1 - q Exp[t] ?

Comment: The problem is:

Random variable X has a geometric distribution with parameter P.

Calculate the moment generating function of X. Then use the MGF to compute the mean.

Comment: It is not a typo. It is on the solution pdf that the professor sent out. However, I am having a hard time following the derivations since their is minimal steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer given, I believe the problem was misstated; most likely it is asking to find the derivative of the function
$$f(t) = \frac{pe^t}{1-qe^t}$$
To calculate the derivative, we use the quotient rule:
$$ \frac{df}{dt} = \frac{(1-qe^t)\frac{d}{dt}pe^t - pe^t\frac{d}{dt}(1-qe^t)}{(1-qe^t)^2}$$

Our task is then to determine what $\frac{d}{dt} e^t$ is. Any calculus textbook will state that it is equal to itself, but proving this requires a more sophisticated definition of the exponential function: as the inverse of the natural logarithm, which is defined as $ln(x) = \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$.

From the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $\frac{d}{dt} ln(t) = \frac{1}{t}$. Now consider that $ln(e^t) = t$ (since the functions are inverses). Taking the derivatives of both sides with respect to $t$,

$$\frac{d}{dt} ln(e^t) = \frac{1}{e^t} \frac{d}{dt} e^t = 1$$

which implies that $\frac{d}{dt} e^t = e^t$.

Returning to our original problem, we obtain

$$\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{(1-qe^t)pe^t - pe^t(-qe^t)}{(1-qe^t)^2} = \frac{pe^t-pqe^{2t} + pqe^{2t}}{(1-qe^t)^2} = \frac{pe^t}{(1-qe^t)^2}$$

where I used the property that $e^te^t = e^{2t}$.

Comment: I think this is what I needed to use. The quotient rule. I forgot these existed. Thanks.

Comment: @Alqatrkapa:  nice definition of $e^t$!

Answer (score 0):

Please observe that

$P*{e}^t/[(1-q)*{e}^t] = pe^t / [(1 -q)e^t] = p / (1- q), \tag{1}$

whence

$(pe^t / (1 - q)e^t])' = 0, \tag{2}$

assuming $P = p$ and $p, q$ are constants.  This forces me to agree with Alqatrkapa's assessment that the correct function to be differentiated is very likely

$f(t) = pe^t / (1-qe^t); \tag{3}$

and I refer the reader to the most excellent analysis in his answer for the derivative of this function.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!***